# Use "Alias" in "Select" With Medoo

Tags: select, frameworks, alias

I'm using the Medoo framework.

I need this query:

```
Select a.name, b.name from section as a left join section as b on(a.idsection=b.section_idfather)
```

In the Medoo format:

```
$Data = $database->select("section", 
                [
                "[>]section" => ["idsection" => "section_idfather"]
                ], 
                [
                "section.name",
                "section.name",
                ]
]);
```

How can I do this query in the right Medoo format??

Answer (score 0):

So, I change a litty the original file to get assign an ALIAS to the Select Columns:

1) Add in the LINE: 127

protected function column_quote_as($string)
    {
            return str_replace('.', '`.`', $string);
    }

2) Add in the LINE: 405 (original line)

```
foreach($columns AS $Columns){
            $columnsTemp =explode('[>]',$Columns);
            $columnsVal = ($columnsTemp[1]!='') ? '`' . $columnsTemp[0] . '` AS \'' . $columnsTemp[1] . '\'':'`' .$columnsTemp[0] . '`';
            $ColumnsEnd[] = $columnsVal;
        }
```

3) Change the LINE: 408 (original line)

```
is_array($ColumnsEnd) ? $this->column_quote_as( implode(', ', $ColumnsEnd) ) :
```

And now, the new format to take the query is:

```
$Data = $database->select("section", 
                [
                "[>]section" => ["idsection" => "section_idfather"]
                ], 
                [
                "section.name[>]SecName",
                "section.name[>]SecNameFather",
                ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses to add an alias for a column name.

```
$data = $database->select("account", [
    "user_id",
    "nickname (my_nickname)"
]);
```

For joins:

```
$data = $database->select("post (content)", [
    "[>]account (user)" => "user_id",
], [
    "content.user_id (author_id)",
    "user.user_id"
]);
```